# Jquery click handler from setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have `<a>` element which clicked runs handler like:

```
function onCummReportClick(e) {
    if ($(e.currentTarget).attr('href').indexOf('csv') !== -1) {
    {
        return true;
    }

       //Here some files loaded asynchronousely
    $.ajax().success(...).always(...);

    var reports = [];
    var downloadedCount = 0;
    var reportsCount = 9;

    var oneDownloaded = function() {
        if (downloadedCount === reportsCount) {
            //Prepare cummulative reports CSV
            $(e.currentTarget).attr('href', 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,'+ encodeURI(reports.join('\n\n')))

            //HERE!
            $(e.currentTarget).trigger('click');
        } else {
            setTimeout(oneDownloaded, 1000);
        }
    };

    setTimeout(oneDownloaded, 1000);
}
```

I.e. it download reports, join its content to one CSV and set it as base64-encoded to original `<a>`'s href. After that I want it downloaded automatically without user have to click again.

And `return true` does not generates "normal" click flow, looks like if just skipped. i mean that I running into this handler second time, but download did not started.

If I set up `href` to generated value statically and in handler just returning `true` if works as expected - file automatically downloaded.

I know that I could download reports synchronously and make entire method sync, but I dislike this approach.

**UPD**: I created jsfiddle which demonstrates what I trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/u1rs17w1/

Comment: `e.currentTarget` will change if invoked by `setTimeout` ..

Comment: as mentioned, e is probably no longer valid. Start your function saving a reference to e and use that in the rest of the function

Comment: @RayonDabre why? I still see that it is event and currentTarget still the same - my hyperlink element.

Comment: @dmaij it does not work

Comment: @A1rPun thanks tried you suggestion and it does not works as everything mentioned above.

Comment: @AlexG.P. I see now, everyone who claims the `e.currentTarget` changes is wrong because it is defined in the `onCummReportClick` scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why code from JSFiddle does not works, as I understand all assumption about "lost context" is wrong (at least half wrong) because original hyperlink is updated correctly (I mean `href` attribute uptdated).

But I found another solution. Instead of clicking on original link I do following:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.download = _messages.CUMMULATIVE_REPORT_NAME;
link.href='data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,'+ encodeURI(csvFile.join('\n\n'));

//These 2 lines are required for Firefox
link.style = "display: none";
document.body.appendChild(link);

link.click();
```

And it is works even from `setTimeout` handler. I suspect that clicks by jquery-style, i.e. with `return true` (I cannot call it somehow clearly) works only from main thread. Each time I works with `setTimeout` execution continued in new thread. But creating element in new thread and clicking on it works like a charm!

Happy coding!

**UPD**: This solution does not works in Firefox. Nothing works in Firefox unless synchronous AJAX (ffffffuuuuuuuu!) and `return true`.

**UPD1**: Added solution for Firefox.

Comment: Ok, nice to see it works. I did fiddle around a bit and you can enter a call in your success handler from ajax instead of the timeouts. see https://jsfiddle.net/u1rs17w1/7/ for a diff.